# _rowID not resetting when clearing datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, row, extension-methods

I am using a global datatable called DT, which is defined as

```
Public DT as New DataTable
```

If I load DT with data for 1000 rows, then clear using the syntax below

```
If DT IsNot Nothing Then
    DT.Clear()
    DT.Columns.Clear()
    DT.Rows.Clear()
End If
```

Once cleared, I then load DT with a new (qry,cn) which has 50 rows, however, the rowID values for the new dataset are now 1001, 1002, ..., 1050.

FYI, I am getting rowID from the following method:

```
For Each row As DataRow In DT.Rows
    MsgBox(row.RowId)
Next

Public Module ExtensionMethods
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function RowId(ByVal row As DataRow) As Integer
        Dim fieldInfo As Reflection.FieldInfo =
            row.GetType().GetField("_rowID",
                Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(fieldInfo.GetValue(row))
        Return value
    End Function
End Module
```

**UDPATE**

The Code used each time a new data query/connection is made for re-loading the DT and a DataGridView.  Using DT.Dispose before loading new data (connection,query) from a different file does not remove the previous data from the DataGridView.

```
        If DT IsNot Nothing Then
            DT.Dispose()
        End If
        qry = "SELECT * FROM " & "[" & myAccessTable & "]"
        Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(qry, cn)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader
        GlobalDataTable.Load(dr)

        Dim dgv1 As New DataGridView
        dgv1.Name = "dgv1"
        dgv1.DataSource = GlobalDataTable.DefaultView
        dgv1.AutoSize = True
        dgv1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both
        dgv1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
        dgv1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
        dgv1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Blue
        dgv1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Gray
        dgv1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both
        dgv1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        dgv1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Sans Typewriter", 8)
        dgv1.GetType.InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, dgv1, New Object() {True})
```

Comment: Dispose of the DataTable instead of *clearing* it (in a weird way, btw). After that, the Row IDs are reset. Note that `_rowID` is an `Int64` value, not an `int`, your cast should fail. You need to cast to `long`. -- You shouldn't need/use this value, though, it's internal use.

Comment: Got a couple questions on this.  1) Why does it matter?  RowId is typically an internal identification thing and the exact value doesn't matter.  2) What is the purpose of clearing the DT?  3) Why not just simply create a new instance of the DT instead of clearing it?

Comment: (see updated OP).  Using DT.Dispose does not seem to clear the data from DT, which are visible in the DataGridView.  But the problem may be in the DataGridView.   DGV1.Invalidate does not help.

Comment: Yeah, I've gone through this a few times now.  Honestly something just smells like bad design here.  It's not really the norm to have a single datatable reference used for multiple result sets.  I suspect that bad design is why you're now have the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: I may be missing the point here but don't these Access tables have primary keys to uniquely identify the rows?

Comment: Sometimes an Excel file is read and loaded into DT, so an auto increment ID (primary key like in Access) is not always present.  The issue is that _rowID is not being cleared from DT after .Clear, .Columns.Clear, .Rows.Clear are invoked.  Dispose prevents new data/columns from loading correctly.  Why does _rowID keep incrementing when new data are read in after clearing?  Can the Extension be disposed if it IsNot Nothing?

Comment: As @Hursey commented; `RowId` is an internal member of the `DataRow Class`. It's **not** supposed to be accessible from your code. That's why you are having to use Reflection to fetch its value. If you really need to have some sort of row Id/counter then add an `AutoIncrement Column` to the `DataTable` before you populate it. See [the documents here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.autoincrement?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @stevec, that's what I have been thinking -- to inject my own rowid via autoincrement.  Although I do detect if an e.g. .accdb has an autoincrement field using `If c.ColumnName.ToString = "ID" AndAlso InStr(c.DataType.ToString, "System.Int32") Then`, it's not clear if there will be other System.Int32 fields in an Access database.  If think if a field is a "Number" it will be a Double, so I'm not sure if Access can have Int32 fields other than autoincrement?

Comment: @wrstks yes, an access db can have Int32 columns that are not autoincrement.  I know very little about databases, but I wonder if it might be more reliable to examine the table schema using the [OleDbDataReader.GetSchemaTable Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getschematable?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)? Or just add your own autoincrement column in any case. Would it harm? You don't need to write it back to the DataBase Table. I guess it depends on what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for when a different Excel is opened, and a developer wishes to re-populate a global DataTable, and also invoke a unique ID column, which is hidden.  The hidden ID column can be used for sorting before replacing elements in DT, and to pick off row values when filtering from DT after filtering:

```
    ‘If global DataTable is full, clear it
    If DT IsNot Nothing Then
        DT.Clear()
        DT.Columns.Clear()
    End If

    ‘Setup your own autoincrement field called my _myID (which is hidden in DT)
    Dim col As New DataColumn
    col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
    col.AutoIncrement = True
    col.AutoIncrementStep = 1
    col.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
    col.ColumnName = "_myID"
    DT.Columns.Add(col)

    ‘Fetch NumInputFields, and InputFieldNames arrays from Excel file, then populate DT

    numaddedcolumns = 0
    For j = 0 To NumInputFields - 1
        iscolumnexist = False
        Try
            If DT.Columns.Contains(InputFieldNames(j + 1)) Then
                iscolumnexist = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        If iscolumnexist = False Then
            DT.Columns.Add(InputFieldNames(j + 1), GetType(Object))
        End If
        If iscolumnexist = True Then
            numaddedcolumns += 1
            InputFieldNames(j + 1) &= "_" & numaddedcolumns
            DT.Columns.Add(InputFieldNames(j + 1), GetType(Object))
        End If
    Next

    Dim workrow As DataRow
    For i = 1 To NumInputObjects
        workrow = DT.NewRow()
        ‘You have to initially fill an AutoIncrement field with integer values inside the loop.  So do this before looping through all input fields, for this row.  
        workrow("_myID") = i
        For j = 1 To NumInputFields
            workrow(j) = ExcelDataArray(i, j)
        Next
        DT.Rows.Add(workrow)
    Next

    ‘Set AutoIncrementSeed to the row count of the data just added
    DT.Columns("_myID").AutoIncrementSeed = DT.Rows.Count

    ‘Populate a DataGridView with data from DT (with the autoincrement ID column hidden)
    Dim dgv1 As New DataGridView
    dgv1.Name = "dgv1"
    With dgv1
        .AutoGenerateColumns = True
        .DataSource = DT
        .Refresh()
        .AutoSize = True
        .ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both
        .DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
        .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
        .DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Blue
        .DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Gray
        .ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        .Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Sans Typewriter", 8)
        .GetType.InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, dgv1, New Object() {True})
    End With

    ‘Finally, as usual, add the DataGridView to Form1, or another control.
    Form1.Controls.Add(dgv1)
```